# E/SpannableStringBuilder(22708): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length on rotation screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I just started learning android, in my application I can switch between two fragments, I have a problem when the orientation of the screen changes, in the logCat I get the red strings:

```
    08-24 13:14:20.970: E/SpannableStringBuilder(22708): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-24 13:14:20.980: E/SpannableStringBuilder(22708): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

the app does not crash, but the two fragments are overlapped.
this is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.eximia.lamiaspesaapp.app.ScanActivity"
android:background="@drawable/fondale">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


</FrameLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:background="@drawable/titolo_top"
    android:contentDescription="@string/titolotop"
    android:paddingLeft="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

and my two fragments:

fragment_scan:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.eximia.lamiaspesaapp.ScanFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/carica_button"
    android:background="@drawable/ico_carica"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dispensa_button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/scarica_button"
    android:background="@drawable/ico_scarica"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/carica_button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scan_button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/scan_button" />"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/dispensa_button"
    android:background="@drawable/ico_prodotti"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/scan_button"
    android:background="@drawable/ico_verifica"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dispensa_button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

fragment_product:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.eximia.lamiaspesaapp.ProductFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scan_format"
    android:layout_width="133dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scan_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/scan_format"
    />

<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/immagine_prodotto"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/immagine_prodotto"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/testo_descrizione"
    android:layout_below="@+id/immagine_prodotto"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />




<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/testo_prodotto"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/testo_descrizione"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/testo_descrizione" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Modalità"
    android:id="@+id/testo_sviluppo"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/immagine_prodotto" />

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp" />
```

somebody says that is related   third part library that my phone "samsung galaxy star" uses; how can I see if this is my case?

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same error all the time. In my case It is from SwiftKey keyboard applocation, If i Switch to AOSP keyboard it is not there anymore. You don't have worry about this error it wont crash your app in anyway.

If you are having problems with fragments while rotating the screen most likely because of your logic in creating the activity/adding fragments.Remember by default when you rotate your screen the whole activity is recreated (ie. on create is called again + all saved fragments resotred). put a break point on create and rotate you might see whats the problem. usally this is tackled by checking for a fragment before adding. post some of your code if possible.

Comment: yes the application does not crash, but my two fragment are overlapped   I can see both, they are visible at the same time, that is wrong for me, maybe the problem is, how I do the transaction.

Comment: If you are having problems with fragments while rotating the screen most likely because of your logic in creating the activity/adding fragments.Remember by default when you rotate your screen the whole activity is recreated (ie. on create is called again + all saved fragments resotred). put a break point on create and rotate you might see whats the problem. usally this is tackled by checking for a fragment before adding. post some of your code if possible.

Comment: Thanks, do you think I should work with the savedInstance bundle? It makes sense, because after the first transaction the view should be recreated with the last fragment.

Comment: yes play with saved instance and where you are adding fragment